# Pagination MYSQL count vs PHP count and array_slice

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

I have a search query which looks for matching values from a search table and returns all possible entries matching the keywords. I did not write the search, it's something that already existed and we're porting it to another framework. Anyway, that's not the point.

What I want is to execute a MySQL query (InnoDB), using `LIMIT`, and have the `COUNT` of all results at my disposal for **pagination** (to calculate number of total pages). I assumed using `LIMIT` has some effect on the speed but after measuring execution time it doesn't seem to have much (atleast in this case).

**The problem:**

Using a separate query to `COUNT` rows (just count) takes as much time as the real query. In this case approximately 11 seconds so the entire execution is about 22 seconds.

```
// Fetch Count approximately 11 seconds
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE ...

// Fetch All approximately 11 seconds
SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE ...
```

Another method I used was to just search without `LIMIT` and then use `PHP`'s own `count()` function to get the number of results I got, then `array_slice()` to limit the number of entries for the page. This actually proved to be faster as the query took about 12 seconds and `PHP` a fraction of a second. So it's about half.

```
// Fetch All approximately 11-12 seconds
$results = SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE ...
// PHP count and slice took a fraction of a second
$count = count($results);
$results = array_slice($results, $page, $limit);
```

I also tried to use `COUNT` inside the first `LIMIT` query so I wouldn't have to use a separate query for it but it seems `PDO`'s own `fetchAll` returns variating results in each array entry. What I got was 2, 1,  1, 1...

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as `count`, id, name FROM table WHERE ...
```

**The question:**

What is the fastest way to actually query results for pagination having the results and result count at your disposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second option is not an option at all.

On the other hand, 11 seconds is still absolutely unacceptable. So, to make your code proper, you have to **optimize** the search query. This should be your goal and concern.

Comment: Thank you! You were absolutely correct. As I said at the top, the search was not our doing but I optimized it by first searching the ids for entries I need to search in another table (from the search table) as they were searched via LEFT JOIN before, then I just added those ids in the WHERE clause. Execution time dropped to 1\10th.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can i ask which is the best method? I am looking at this issue now and trying to find the best way to speed up.

I am currently using

```
// Fetch All Rows 
$results = SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE ...
// PHP count and slice took a fraction of a second
$count = count($results);
$results = array_slice($results, $page, $limit);
```

I am not able to find out the performance of array_slice so not sure if it is the best method or should I revert back to especially for large dataset

```
// Fetch Count of all rows for pagination
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE ...

// Fetch the require rows
SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE ...
```